# php include a file with a variable name?

Tags: php, file, cookies, include

I am trying to include a file from a cookie

say my cookie has a value

```
$file = $_COOKIE['PageValue'];
```

I  want to include this file like this

```
include '$file';
```

is there a way of achieving this?

cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
if( file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file){
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file; 
}
```

!! A VERY BIG WARNING !!
This example is TOO simple. ALWAYS validate userinput, especially when including files.

Good practice would be checking if $file is in an array with allowed $files, or maybe check in a database.

This is a fragile part, XSS is just arround the corner.

You might want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

See [this link:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#86842) from the manual

```
 include $_COOKIE['PageValue'];
```

You may want to add null checks and constraints if you're not sure if the value would always return valid values

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you wrote the answer:

```
include $file; // No quotes!
```

But, you should sanitize your input, best do a whitelisting of files possible to include. For further help, post example of your code, or give us further info what you're trying to accomplish.